# React router redux Link changing route, but not component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

In my application I am using

```
"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-dom": "^15.4.2",
"react-redux": "^5.0.3",
"react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"redux": "^3.6.0"
```

and in my codes I have a Link (import {Link} from "react-router-dom";)

```
<Link to="login">Login</Link>
```

When I click on it, it is changing the url, also in the redux dev tool I can see that routing pathname is being changed, but the component for login path is not becoming visible.

You can check the code on my [Github](https://github.com/haykaghabekyan/react-redux/blob/master/src/public/js/index.js) repository

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4671)

The problem is that in the beta react-router version you need to wrap exported component into withRouter like in the code bellow

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

Here is my [commit](https://github.com/haykaghabekyan/react-redux/commit/a3fb53cbcf6d3e9fd3dfb5d6bcc41acc0d429d53) in my github project

Answer (score 0):

Inside Your `<Router>` add entry:

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login}>
```

Without it React don't know which component should be used.

And login in Link should be preceeding by slash:

```
<Link to="/login">Login</Link>
```

Comment: I have that. https://github.com/haykaghabekyan/react-redux/blob/master/src/public/js/app.js

Comment: I see such solution first time. First try to add slash before login in Link. If it didn't work. move your   Routes to Router.

Comment: I should look like here https://github.com/haykaghabekyan/react-redux/blob/master/src/public/js/utils/routes.js. I don't know why You are defining routes in 2 different places.

Comment: I am adding that in App component, so I can connect it with redux, but I have tried that writing in index.js and the same problem there was available.